# How to export the file json to CSV or XLSX format in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

> Im new to angularjs and im trying to export the data xlsx format but
>   my data is not coming can any one help me out in this how to export
>   since i have parse the json data csv also but still if any can help it
>   would easy for please make it in fiddle and send me, thanks in
>   advance.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<button ng-click="exportData()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;padding-right:10px;">Export&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
</html>
```

js file is

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('exportreportController', ['$stateParams','$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$location', 'dashboardService', 'Flash','$http','$timeout',
function ($stateParams,$rootScope, $scope, $state, $location, dashboardService, Flash,$http,$timeout) {

 $scope.inverters = [
  {
    "InvDetails": "UPS",
    "LstRecords": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
        "Lastreading": 0,
        "Readingby": 0
      },
      {
        "Id": 87,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
        "Lastreading": 5,
        "Readingby": 10
      },
      {
        "Id": 110,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 10,
        "Readingby": 92
      },
      {
        "Id": 111,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 92,
        "Readingby": 95
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "InvDetails": "Power Supply",

    "LstRecords": [
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
        "Lastreading": 0,
        "Readingby": 0
      },
      {
        "Id": 88,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
        "Lastreading": 7,
        "Readingby": 13
      },
      {
        "Id": 109,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 13,
        "Readingby": 25
      },
      {
        "Id": 112,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 25,
        "Readingby": 49
      }
    ]
  }
];

     $scope.exportData = function () {
        //alert("exporting");
        // var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('example1').innerHTML], {
        //     type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        // });
        // saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
        var data="";
        $scope.headers=[];
         angular.forEach($scope.inverters,function(value,key){
// debugger
        var we=value.InvDetails;
        $scope.headers.push(we);
        $scope.last=value.LstRecords;
        angular.forEach($scope.last,function(value,key){

    data={
        "Id": value.Id,
        "Invertor_Id": value.Invertor_Id,
        "Time_of_Reading":value.Time_of_Reading,
        "Lastreading": value.Lastreading,
         "Readingby": value.Readingby
        };
        })
    })

         $scope.result=[];
         $scope.result0=[];
         $scope.result.push({
        "Invertor1":JSON.stringify(data)
         })
         // debugger
        alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[$scope.result]);
    };
    }]);
```

> i need to export this one csv or xlsx please help me in this i have
>   searched in google but i didnt get exact solution to this.... please
>   help me out. just i want to export the data in report wise since it is
>   a report generation.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed something alike, ng-csv and other solutions didn't completely help. My data was in $scope and there were no HTML tables showing it. So, I built a directive to export json data to Excel using Sheet.js (xslsx.js) and FileSaver.js.

[Here is my solution packed.](https://jsfiddle.net/kursadgulseven/cd0fmg0r/)

For example, the data is:

```
$scope.jsonToExport = [
    {
      "col1data": "1",
      "col2data": "Fight Club",
      "col3data": "Brad Pitt"
    },
    {
      "col1data": "2",
      "col2data": "Matrix Series",
      "col3data": "Keanu Reeves"
    },
    {
      "col1data": "3",
      "col2data": "V for Vendetta",
      "col3data": "Hugo Weaving"
    }
];
```

I had to prepare data as array of arrays for my directive in my controller:

```
$scope.exportData = [];
// Headers:
$scope.exportData.push(["#", "Movie", "Actor"]);
// Data:
angular.forEach($scope.jsonToExport, function(value, key) {
  $scope.exportData.push([value.col1data, value.col2data, value.col3data]);
});
```

Finally, add directive to my template. It shows a button. (See [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kursadgulseven/cd0fmg0r/)).

```
<div excel-export export-data="exportData" file-name="{{fileName}}"></div>
```

Comment: but my data in nested json array fromat which i dont no how to convert in csv, since im struggling from yesterday please let me know if u can fetch my nested data it would eacsy for me thanks

Comment: please do with my json data n send me, it would be easy for me, when ever im trying im getting errors only.  i googled also but not similar one which have nested json array data.. please do with this josn, thanks

Comment: You can use another `angular.forEach` inside the one I provided in the answer. _"I can only show you the door. You're the one that has to walk through it."_ -- [Morpheus](http://www.quotes.net/mquote/60255)

Comment: im sorry to say that i have tried that inserting the another foreach loop since it was not coming so only i asked apart from nothing. as u said, like that more datas r coming means how to do that is what i asked, im sorry if my question is hearted u

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.exportData = function (file_name,output_type,data) {
   if(output_type=="xlsx"){
         file_name=file_name+".xlsx";
         alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("'+file_name+'",{headers:true}) FROM ?', 
         [data]);
   }
   else{
         file_name=file_name+".csv";
         alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV("'+file_name+'",{headers:true}) FROM ?', 
         [data]);
   }

}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<button ng-click="exportData('file_','csv',inverters)" class="btn btn-primary" >Export CSV<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
<button ng-click="exportData('file_','xlsx',inverters)" class="btn btn-primary" >Export CSV<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></button>
</html>
```